# Clear parent element css properties for children element

Tags: css

I have two elemnt, for example:

```
 <div style="color: #f00">
    parent 
    <div>child</div>
 </div>
```

I want, that child element not haves parent CSS properties, please tell, how can make this?

Comment: Just set it to something else for the child element?

Comment: But if parent element has very many childrens (and they have self childrens and etc.) and must clear parent properties for all children, what do to? no another way ?

Comment: Then don't change the parent element, but put everything which needs another style into another container.

Answer (score 1):

You can

1. Put all of the children into an `<iframe>`. The parent window's CSS won't be reflected within the iframe.
2. You can modify a CSS reset like http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ to suit your needs *(ie. edit and prefix each section of the reset with the selector to your children as necessary)*.

   ```
   <div style="color: #f00">
     parent 
     <div id="children">
       <div>child</div>
     </div>
   </div>
   ```

*(just using the last line of the reset above as an example)*, you could do something like

```
#children table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

to reset `<table>` elements within `#children`. You have to test and tweak this for your own needs.

Answer (score 0):

a child div will always inherit the styling of its parent div, that is what css is all about. You could consider something like this

```
<div class='parent'>
  parent text
    <div>
       child text
    </div>
</div>
```

then in your styles (somwhere in your html, or prefarbly in a linked stylesheet) you could do something like this:

```
body, .parent div {
  color: #000;
  ...
}
.parent {
  color: #f00;
  ...
}
```

note that if you add more styling to the `.parent`, you would have to set an alternative for the child divs  (`.parent div`) to prevent that property from beeing inherited by the children